# How to label an oTree Slider widget using a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, otree

I am trying to label a slider as in [jQuery UI Slider Labels Under Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224856/jquery-ui-slider-labels-under-slider). I am not dealing with a ui-slider however, but rather with the slider widget from oTree.

The excellent answer to the question [Mandatory slider in oTree/django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113641/mandatory-slider-in-otree-django) explains how to use a jQuery selector to select an oTree slider:

```
$('[data-slider] input[type="range"]')
```

I have a slider that shows the current selected value (0-100). What I would like to do is to add a few labels below the slider (e.g. "cold", "neutral", "warm" if the slider value is a temperature). I tried the following code to select the oTree slider and append labels, but no labels appear.

```
{% formfield player.mySliderInput type="Slider"}

{% block scripts %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mylabel = $('<label>25</label>').css('left', '25%');
    $('[data-slider] input[type="range"]').append(mylabel);
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

The HTML of the page looks as follows:

```
<div class="form-group required">     
  <label class="col-form-label" for="id_myInput">How hot is it? (0-100):</label>
  <div class="controls  field-myInput">
    <div class="input-group slider" data-slider>
      <input type="range" name="myInput" value="None"
        step="1"
        min="0"
        max="100"
        required
        id="id_myInput"
        class="form-control"
      />

      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text" data-slider-value title="current value"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am unsure of which object (div? input?) to select and append the labels to.

Comment: Can you view source on page and post the input element HTML here?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I included the HTML above.

Comment: Maybe I need to append my labels to the "input-group-append" instead, rather than the "data-slider"?

Comment: Label usually would surround the input but w otree and django etc who knows.   Try the selector on id element as I suggested,  if it doesn't work we can try the div

Comment: Updated answer with label syntax

Comment: Did it work?  Please accept if so.   Thanks!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Apologies for the delay, @BrianPatterson. It does not work yet, I'm afraid. I updated the question to explain in more detail what exactly I'm trying to achieve, since I think the problem is that I do not know which object (div, label, input) to append the labels to. Thanks a lot for your continued support, I will certainly accept an answer once I solved this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update..

As per OP comments,  the selector that ended up being appended to for the oTree slider was `.controls`

```
var $label = $('<label>sometext</label>').css('left', '10%'); 
$('.controls').append($label);
```

---

Original...

Using the has attribute selector (https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) you can select by an attribute.

```
<input type="range" data-slider="someval">
```

Given above html..  You can select it with...

```
[data-slider]
```

Adding in `input[type="range"]` will further qualify result to only include type range.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help! I have included example code above. What I'm struggling with is that oTree uses Django expressions, so I haven't been able to find the relevant HTML attributes. Any idea where I could look for these? (My Django knowledge is very limited.)

Comment: View source on generated page possible? Then search for type="range" to find the element code

Comment: Thank you for the update. I seem to lack conceptual knowledge of what I want to append these labels to: the div or the input element? It seems that oTree already is setting up a separate div for showing the current value of the slider - do I need to use this same div to show some labels under the slider?

Comment: Are we talking HTML `<label>` element or simply wanting to append text to label the slider?  You can pron just position or float a div for that.   Otherwise,  I usually wrap input in label.  But may not behave as expected depending on what CSS/jquery is acting on those elements via otree etc

Comment: We're talking about the latter. I updated the question to describe what I'm trying to achieve: to add text labels below the slider (e.g. "cold"/"neutral"/"hot").

Comment: `var $label = $('<label>sometext</label>').css('left', '10%');
 $('.controls').append($label);` did the trick. It looks like the div of class "controls" (as seen in the above HTML) works as a selector for the oTree slider. Feel free to include this in your answer @BrianPatterson, your answers were of tremendous help in figuring this out.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm always happy to help.   Nice job on figuring out that controls selector.   Glad you got it handled.  :)

Answer (score 2):

since then oTree has slightly changed the form class naming.

use the code below:

```
{% block scripts %}
<script>
    $(function () {
        var SliderTouched = false;
        var selector = $('[data-slider] input[type="range"]');
        selector.change(function () {
            SliderTouched = true;
        });

        $("#form").submit(function (event) {
            if (!SliderTouched) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

What it does is the following:

1. It sets a variable to `false` when the page is loaded.
2. Unless this variable (`SliderTouched`) remains false the form will not submit
3. When you touch the slider the variable sets True so the form can be submitted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer, Philipp! The change being to use "#form" instead of ".form", you mean? I am primarily trying to understand how selecting the slider works, however. I am trying to achieve something different with this selector: to label the slider as in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224856/jquery-ui-slider-labels-under-slider) Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: Bravo for knowing this but I believe he's asking for explanation on selector criteria.  Still upvoting this as relevant.

Comment: don't forget to include the reference to jquery-ui (something like that or put it to `static`:     <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
because otherwise the method `slider` that they use in the example you referenced to, won't work, because oTree by default includes only jquery, not jquery-ui

Comment: Thank you for the hint. That didn't do the trick, since I believe oTree is not actually working with a jquery-ui slider, right? I am trying to label the slider that oTree produces (and am unsure as of whether this is the jquery-ui one).